# Automatic translation of utf-8 into ascii using stringi and stringr in R - Error with escape character \u

Tags: r, escaping, string-conversion, stringr, stringi

I am struggling to translate utf-8 into ascii letters automatically.

In a data frame I have the following sequence which originates from greek letters:

```
<U+03A0><U+0391><U+039D><U+0391>G
```

By manually converting the sequence to

```
\u03A0\u0391\u039D\u0391G
```

I got the correct transscription by using **stringi** using this command:

```
t <- "\u03A0\u0391\u039D\u0391G" # original "ΠΑΝΑΓ"
t <- stri_trans_general(t,"any-latin")
t <- stri_trans_general(t,"latin-ascii")
print(t)
[1] "PANAG"
```

Now, I want to automate the translation via **stringr** using:

```
t2 <- "<U+03A0><U+0391><U+039D><U+0391>G"
t2 <- str_replace_all(t2,">","")
t2 <- str_replace_all(t2,"<U+","\\u") # double \\ for the escape character
```

The result is:

```
[1] "+03A0+0391+039D+0391G"
```

Which cannot be translated via **stringi**

May question to you is how to translate the original utf-8 string via **stringr** and **stringi** into ascii letters, as in  my dataframe are a lot of those string sequences?

I am running RStudio Version 0.99.825 on R

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252
```

RStudio and R are running as portable apps.

Thank you in advance

Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `t2 <- str_replace_all(t2,"<U+","\u")` doesn't work is because `\u` starts a unicode character and R expects the hex-code of the character after the `\u`. Therefore, you need to use `\\\\u`, which inserts the string `"\u"` (you need to escape twice: once for R and once for `gsub`).  However, then you end up with the *string* `"\u03A0"` which is not the same as `"\u03A0"` typed in the console/sourced from file. The trick I used below is to parse the string.

There, should probably be a simpler way to do this but the following works:

```
 library(stringi)

str <- "<U+03A0><U+0391><U+039D><U+0391>G"

t <- gsub("<U\\+", "\\\\u", str)
t <- gsub(">", "", t)
t <- eval(parse(text=paste0('"', t, '"')))

t <- stri_trans_general(t,"any-latin")
stri_trans_general(t,"latin-ascii")
```