# Extracting particular information of character variables

Tags: r, string, extract

for a side project, I am currently trying to make a dashboard based on this data (a kind of scatterplot) where there is a date and how the prices change over time. I am currently in one of the hardest states (data cleaning).
I am trying to split the variables in order to extract information. For example, in the variable `departure_info` I want to split into the variable `departure_info_time` and `departure_info_day`. Furthermore, in the variable `price` I want to extract the numbers such as 358, 480, 590, etc.

```
df1 <- data.frame(depart = c("OSL", "WAW", "VIE", "MUC", "FRA"),
                  destination = c("KEF", "ARN", "RIX", "VCE", "OSL"),
                  departue_info = c("['12:45 am Sa 19 Feb']", "['07:55 am Sa 19 Feb']", "['09:05 am Sa 19 Feb']", "['21:45 am Sa 19 Feb', '15:30 am Sa 19 Feb']", "['10:25 am Sa 19 Feb', '16:10 am Sa 19 Feb', '21:40 am Sa 19 Feb']"),
                  price = c("['358<U+0080>']", "['480<U+0080>']", "['590<U+0080>']", "['354<U+0080>', '418<U+0080>']", "['249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '419<U+0080>']"))
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me. I tried with `str_extract()` and `gsub()` but I could not succeed. I also would thank if someone can give me an advice what I have to do, if in a row I have several prices in another row just one.

I thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each item in the `departure_info` has a fixed number of characters, so I use `substr` to extract the substring from the 3rd to 10th character for the time and 12th to 20th for the date.

We could take the same approach for price, but it's a simple regex pattern to look for one or more numbers, `"\\d+"`, so I just use that with `str_extract`, which will extract the **first** occurrence of the pattern, that is the first set of consecutive numbers in the `price` string.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    depart_time = substr(departue_info, start = 3, stop = 10),
    depart_date = substr(departue_info, start = 12, stop = 20),
    price_num = as.numeric(str_extract(price, "\\d+"))
  )
#   depart destination                                                      departue_info
# 1    OSL         KEF                                             ['12:45 am Sa 19 Feb']
# 2    WAW         ARN                                             ['07:55 am Sa 19 Feb']
# 3    VIE         RIX                                             ['09:05 am Sa 19 Feb']
# 4    MUC         VCE                       ['21:45 am Sa 19 Feb', '15:30 am Sa 19 Feb']
# 5    FRA         OSL ['10:25 am Sa 19 Feb', '16:10 am Sa 19 Feb', '21:40 am Sa 19 Feb']
#                                                          price depart_time depart_date price_num
# 1                                              ['358<U+0080>']    12:45 am   Sa 19 Feb       358
# 2                                              ['480<U+0080>']    07:55 am   Sa 19 Feb       480
# 3                                              ['590<U+0080>']    09:05 am   Sa 19 Feb       590
# 4                               ['354<U+0080>', '418<U+0080>']    21:45 am   Sa 19 Feb       354
# 5 ['249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '419<U+0080>']    10:25 am   Sa 19 Feb       249
```

If you want to get all the price numbers, we'll first get rid of the `U0080`s and then use `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract`. This will generate a `list` column, which you can then use in various ways...

```
df1 %>%
  select(price) %>%
  mutate(
    price_num = price %>% str_replace_all(fixed("U+0080"), "") %>% str_extract_all("\\d+")
  )
#                                                         price          price_num
# 1                                              ['358<U+0080>']                358
# 2                                              ['480<U+0080>']                480
# 3                                              ['590<U+0080>']                590
# 4                               ['354<U+0080>', '418<U+0080>']           354, 418
# 5 ['249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '249<U+0080>', '419<U+0080>'] 249, 249, 249, 419
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer. You are the best!!. Sadly I got the following error 
```
Error in substr(departue_info, start = 3, stop = 10) : 
invalid multibyte string, element 289
```
Do you know what can be the reason for that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at your 289th row and see if anything looks different in the `departure_info`. Using `stringr::str_sub` instead of the base `substr` might avoid the error, but if the data is different in that row (and in others) a different approach might be needed.

Comment: You also might want to hold off on "accepting" my answer until you can get it working... if you update your question with problematic data someone might come along with a better method. But if you've accepted the answer everyone will assume no more help is needed.

Comment: You are right I see that  for the month March was written as `M�rz`, I have to figure out a way in which the `ä` can be replaced by a `a`

Comment: This might help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413332/903061

Comment: It worked!!
I Just had to write this one

```
data$departue_info <-  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", data$departue_info)
```

I thank you very much @Gregor Thomas for your help. I am new at Stack Overflow but with the time I will specify my answers and help other people.